# Prove $ 1-\frac{\sum{(z_x - z_y)}^2}{2(n-1)} $ = $\frac{\sum{(z_x*z_y)}}{n-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics, correlation

I am trying to prove the following equality through algebraic means based on the textbook [Applied multiple regression/correlation analysis or the behavioural sciences](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0805822232) by Cohen et al. (pages 27-28) The formulas are supposedly for the Pearson Correlation Coefficient.

$$ 1-\frac{\sum{(z_x - z_y)}^2}{2(n-1)}  = \frac{\sum{(z_x*z_y)}}{n-1}$$

Here $z_x$ and $z_y$ represent z scores for (scores that have been transformed by subtracting the mean from them and dividing by the standard deviation) for two different variables. You are summing over the total number of pairs of scores.

I have tried by manipulating the left hand side of the equation by expanding the terms and converting the 1 to $\frac{n-1}{n-1}$ but I am having no success. Apparently the left hand side can be converted to the right hand side of the equation using only basic algebra. Can someone tell me what I am missing.

Thanks

Comment: You should provide more information about:
1) What do $z_x$ and $z_y$ represent.
2) What are we summing over.

Comment: $z_x$ and $z_y$ represent z scores. You are summing over the total number of pairs of scores. Does that help?

Comment: Not really. You need some condition on $z_i$, otherwise the equality is not necessarily true. Oh wait, you _did_ specify that already! Now, the mean of $z_i$ is 0 and the standard deviation is 1. What does that mean for a $\sum z_i^2$?

Comment: I know I should see it, but I can't see how knowing the mean and SD gives me the sum. Can you explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll use the notation from the book.

So, the z score is calculated as $z_X=\frac{X-M_X}{sd_X}=\frac x{sd_X}$, where $M_X$ is the sample mean of $X$, $x=X-M_X$ and $sd_X=\sqrt{\frac{\sum x^2}{n-1}}$ is the sample standard deviation.

First let's calculate the sum of squared z scores:
\begin{align}
\sum z_X^2&=\sum \left(\frac x{sd_X}\right)^2\\&=\frac1{(sd_X)^2}\sum x^2\\
&=\frac{n-1}{\sum x^2}\sum x^2\\&=n-1.
\end{align}
The same goes for $Y$, i.e. $\sum z_Y^2=n-1$. Then we easily see:
\begin{align}\sum(z_X-z_Y)^2&=\sum(z_X^2-2z_X*z_Y+z_Y^2)\\
&=\sum z_X^2 + \sum z_Y^2 -2\sum z_X*z_Y\\&=2(n-1)-2\sum z_X*z_Y\end{align}

Now the conclusion follows directly:
\begin{align}
1-\frac{\sum(z_X-z_Y)^2}{2(n-1)}&=1-\frac{2(n-1)-2\sum z_X*z_Y}{2(n-1)}\\
&=\frac{\sum z_X*z_Y}{n-1}.
\end{align}